# Please Help_How could use Advanced Logging IIS?

Tags: logging, iis-7

I Download AdvancedLogging64 from microsoft and config it on IIS7 ,but in the resualt text file I have a larg amount of data that I could not find out what it is,How could have them More adjective؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could Analyze the result with WebLogExpert and sql server so nice.the link that help me is here :

http://perftesting.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%3A%20Use%20IIS%20Log%20Files%20In%20Performance%20Testing&ProjectName=perftesting